# Unity3D Rotate only image in button

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm looking for a way to rotate the image of a button without rotating the text.
I tried to fix the rotation of the text like this :

```
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.eulerAngles.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, camera.transform.eulerAngles.y + 90); // Rotation of the whole button
GetComponentInChildren<Text>().transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.zero; // Lock rotation of the text
```

... and it works but the problem is that the text position is moving with the image, like it's fix to it.

I searched on internet but didn't find the same case.
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your text is a child of the button `GameObject` you are rotating, it will be affected as well. Instead of trying to reflect the rotation you should make the image a child of the button and only rotate that `Transform`.

```
button `GameObject`
 — image (rotate this)
 — text `Text`
```